# Run location.replace when the “control” key is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
  document.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    var name = event.key;
    var code = event.code;
    if (name === 'Control') {
   location.replace(classroom.google.com)
    }
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
      alert(`Combination of ctrlKey + ${name} \n Key code Value: ${code}`);
    } else {
      alert(`Key pressed ${name} \n Key code Value: ${code}`);
    }
  }, false);
  // Add event listener on keyup
  document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    var name = event.key;
    if (name === 'Control') {
       location.replace(classroom.google.com)
    }
  }, false);
```

How currently when I press the control key, nothing happens. If I make it run an alert instead, then the alert will successfully run. Do I need to use the window.location function instead?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you aren't passing a `string` to `location.replace()`.

---

Right now, your code looks like this.

```js
location.replace(classroom.google.com);
```

The issue with this code is that you are not surrounding it with quotes to make it a `string`, so JavaScript thinks that you are referencing a property of an object, of an object.

Below is what JavaScript thinks is happening.

```js
const classroom = {
  google: {
    com: undefined,
  }
};

console.log(classroom.google.com); // undefined
```

---

To fix it, simply surround your parameter in quotes, as so.

```js
location.replace("classroom.google.com");
```

This should successfully redirect you to [classroom.google.com](https://classroom.google.com/)!